# SELECT statement error when using where

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT EmployeeName, Date
ORDER BY Date desc 
where Lastname = @lastname
OFFSET 1 Rows 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

If I do not include `where` in above query it perfectly works but how to include `ORDER BY`,`WHERE`, `OFFSET` AND `FETCH` in one statement, I Wanted to select nth row based on Date and lastname

Comment: Please do not include irrelevant tags. This question is not related to c# nor ASP.NET. Read [ask]

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... [JOIN] ... [WHERE] ... [GROUP BY] ... [HAVING] ... [ORDER BY] ... [OFFSET] ... [FETCH FIRST]`

Comment: This cannot work even without your `where` clause... Can it? :|

Comment: No. this query does not perfectly work.

Comment: @jarlh That's `[FROM]`, e.g. `select 42 as TheAnswer where GetDate() > '2020-02-29';`. I've found it handy in the anchor of a CTE.

Comment: @HABO, yes, some dbms products allow that. Nothing I'd recommend since it's neither ANSI SQL nor portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause should be before the `order by` clause.
Also, you are missing the `from` clause.

```
SELECT EmployeeName, Date
FROM <YourTableNameHere>
WHERE Lastname = @lastname
ORDER BY Date desc 
OFFSET 1 Rows 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

(replace `<YourTableNameHere>` with your actual table name)

Comment: Well.. But `FROM` Should be there before `WHERE` right?

Comment: @un-lucky correct. I didn't even see that the `from` clause was missing... edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys!! I believe the answer from Zohar worked!!! :)